# While Loop Break usage

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I am totally going insane over this function I wrote, the while loop wont work for the love of god

```
        while (something something):
            print("at anytime enter 0 for both origin and destination to exit the game")
            o=input("Enter origin stool's index (Must be int) ")
            d=input("Enter destination stool's index (Must be int) ")
            if isinstance(o,int) and isinstance(d,int):#if input d,o are int
               #do bla bla
            elif o==0 and d==0:#to exit manually
               print("Exiting Manually...")
               break
            elif not (isinstance(o,int) and isinstance(d,int)):
               print ("Invalid entry, exiting...")
               break
```

The code should exit when `o` AND `d` are 0, and it should also exit when `o` OR `d` is not an int

However it seems that it doesn't matter what I enter, (i tried 0,0 and 0,1) it returns `invalid entry, exiting...`

Whats wrong with the conditions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 3, the `input` function always returns a string. It doesn't `eval` the user input like it used to do in Python 2. As a result, `o` and `d` are both strings, not integers. You need to wrap your `input` calls with `int(input('...'))` in order to turn them into ints, so your conditionals have a chance of success.

In this case, if the user inputs values that aren't numbers, the `int` call should fail with a `ValueError`. The standard way to deal with this is to wrap any calls to user input with a `try`-`except` block, to deal with users who provide bad input. So the relevant part of your code might look something like this:

```
try:
    o=int(input("Enter origin stool's index (Must be int) "))
    d=int(input("Enter destination stool's index (Must be int) "))
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid entry, exiting...")
    break
```

---

As a side note, your logic in the conditionals is kind of weird/broken. Your first conditional checks whether `a` and `d` are both ints, and then does processing. Then your next conditional (the first `elif` block) tries to compare those to `0`, which will *always fail* since if you get to that test, that means the first conditional failed, so they weren't both ints and therefore can never be equal to `0`.

Comment: Sorry I made some typos with the variables, and also I updated my code so that the first if. I do have one more problem though, my 2nd condition is when it checks for if the variables are not integers, how can I do that if I had to cast the input into int initially?

Comment: @Nick Editing your post for typos is fine, but please don't edit answers into your question; it invalidates the answers. I've edited my answer to make it clearer how to deal with invalid input.

Comment: Sorry, I am pretty inexperienced. Will keep that in mind for the future. Thanks for you help it worked great!

Answer (score 0):

Your first "if" will pass when o and d are ints regardless of their values. Only if that condition fails will it continue through to the next "elif".

Try something more like:

```
if isinstance(o,int) and isinstance(d,int) and (o != 0 or d != 0):
   #Conditions met, carry on
else:
   break
```

Comment: Thanks for the headsup! I noticed that as well after I posted my question :P